# Can not send header 'userId' using Stomp Websocket

Tags: java, websocket, stomp

When I try to send message from Java client to server using command:

```
connectedHeaders.add("userId", UUID.randomUUID().toString());     
session.send("/app/start_smpp", connectedHeaders.getFirst("userId"));
```

I receive error:

```
11:49:43.596 [clientInboundChannel-7] ERROR o.s.w.s.m.WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler - Unhandled exception
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Missing header 'userId' for method parameter type [class java.lang.String]
```

I do not know how to send header userID in java

In js code looks like this:

```
 session.send(destination, {headers}, body);
```